# Problem with outer loop vectorization using OpenMP in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, race-condition, pragma

I am lerning how to use OpenMP to make a code use muttiple processors. Recently, I tried to make my Ewald Summation Fourier part parallel using OpenMP. Below is the function named PME_fourier_oprimized which I try to make parallel using OpenMP pragma where,

```
ParticleN = Number of cahrged particles in the System (an integer number)
kcount = an integer number
qi = prop[i][0] (a double float) which gives charge of a particle i
Ext_L[0] = x dimension of the system (a double float number)
Ext_L[1] = y dimension of the system (a double float number)
Ext_L[1] = z dimension of the system (a double float number)
**r_pos = ParticleNx3 array (r_pos[i][0], r_pos[i][1], and r_pos[i][2] = x, y , and z postions of a particle i)
**PME_mev_ksq = kcountx4 array
**f_kewald = ParticleNx3 array which stores the forces
```

```
 double PME_Fourier_optimized(int kcount, double **r_pos, double **PME_mvec_ksq, double **prop, double **f_kewald, double *Ext_L){
    
    // Auto alpha determination //
    double TRTF = 50*5.5;
    double box_VOL = 8*Ext_L[0]*Ext_L[1]*Ext_L[2]; // calculate the volume of the box //
    alpha = pow((ParticleN*M_PI*M_PI*M_PI*TRTF)/(box_VOL*box_VOL),1./6.); // Ewald cutoff parameter //

    double GAMMA = -0.25/(alpha*alpha);
    double recip = 2*M_PI*ONE_PI_EPS0/(8*Ext_L[0]*Ext_L[1]*Ext_L[2]);
    double e_kewald=0.0;
    
    double fx_kewald[ParticleN];
    double fy_kewald[ParticleN];
    double fz_kewald[ParticleN];

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0;i<ParticleN;i++){
        fx_kewald[i] = 0.0;
        fy_kewald[i] = 0.0;
        fz_kewald[i] = 0.0;
        for (int j=0;j<dimen;j++){
            f_kewald[i][j] = 0.0; 
        }
    }
    
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:e_kewald,fx_kewald[:ParticleN],fy_kewald[:ParticleN],fz_kewald[:ParticleN])
    for(int k=0; k<kcount; k++){
        
        double ak_cos=0.0;
        double ak_sin=0.0;
        
        double mx = PME_mvec_ksq[k][0]; 
        double my = PME_mvec_ksq[k][1];
        double mz = PME_mvec_ksq[k][2];
        double ksq = PME_mvec_ksq[k][3];

        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ak_sin,ak_cos)
        for(int i=0;i<ParticleN;i++){
            double qi = prop[i][0]; // charge of particle i //
            double kdotr = mx*r_pos[i][0] + my*r_pos[i][1] + mz*r_pos[i][2];

            ak_sin -= qi*sin(kdotr);
            ak_cos += qi*cos(kdotr);
        }
        
        double a = ak_cos;
        double b = ak_sin;

        double akak = (a*a + b*b);
        double tmp = recip * exp(GAMMA*ksq)/ksq;
        
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:fx_kewald[:ParticleN],fy_kewald[:ParticleN],fz_kewald[:ParticleN])
        for(int i=0;i<ParticleN;i++){
            double qi = prop[i][0];
            double kdotr = mx*r_pos[i][0] + my*r_pos[i][1] + mz*r_pos[i][2];
            double tmp2 = 2*tmp*qi*(sin(kdotr) * a + cos(kdotr) * b);
            
            //Edit3: Following @Laci advice to use 1D array to store the forces and using the reduction to gain a huge acceleration compared to only using omp critical (See the comment section for more details).

            fx_kewald[i] += tmp2 * mx; 
            fy_kewald[i] += tmp2 * my; 
            fz_kewald[i] += tmp2 * mz;
        }
        
        e_kewald += tmp * akak; // add the energies for each k //
    }
    
    //Edit3: Finally storing the calculated values in the 2D array //
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<ParticleN;i++){
        f_kewald[i][0] = fx_kewald[i];
        f_kewald[i][1] = fy_kewald[i];
        f_kewald[i][2] = fz_kewald[i];
    }

    //printf("PME KEwald: %lf\n", e_kewald);
    return e_kewald; 
}
```

I compared this code output with my serial code version and notied there is an error in the e_kewald energy and f_kewald force after 2 decimal places. Interestingly, I get differnt results each time I run it (maybe it is the case of data race).

When I **remove the first pragma command ( #pragma omp parallel for private(k, mx, my, mz, ksq, qi, kdotr, tmp2) reduction(+:e_kewald) ) before the outer k loop**, it **starts to work perfectly** and matches perfectly with the serial code result. Is there something that I am doing grossly wrong? I am also not sure if the way I did use pargma is correct or not. Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit1: After using the #pragma omp critical before the f_kewald array solves the problem. But, not sure if it's the best way to do it.

My 2d arrays are defined using the following function:

```
double **alloc_2d_double(int rows, int cols){
    int i=0;
    double *data = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
    double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double *));
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}
```

I am still wondering if the f_kewald[i][0], f_kewald[i][1], f_kewald[i][2] can be use under the reduction.

Edit2: Declaring the variables inside the loop and putting the braces in the omp critical section.

ParticleN ~ 5000-10000
kcount ~ 2000

Edit3: Using 1D arrays (fx_kewald, fy_kewald, fz_kewald) with reduction to gain enhanced parallelization speed instead of a opm critical section with 2D arrays. (Thanks to the @Laci's comment below)

Comment: Shouldn't akak and tmp be private?

Comment: I put akak and tmp in the private but still no luck.

Comment: Make all your loop variables declared in the loop header. That literally solves half of all questions posted about OpenMP.

Comment: All that `**` stuff is not a good way to program. You're not giving the code so I can't see if you create the arrays correctly, but let's assume so. For memory locality it's a better idea to allocate 2D arrays as a contiguous block.

Comment: Just a silly question of mine: you're doing nested parallelism here. Is that intentional? How are you managing it?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I have edited my question to include how I made the 2d arrays, but not sure if the memory is allocated as a contiguous block or not.

Comment: @Gilles I tried the nested parallelism to gain speed up, but after putting #pragma omp critical, not sure whether the nested things are at all needed.

Comment: @Seth Your arrays are indeed allocated as pointers into one contiguous block. Good. You should still declare the loop variables in the loop headers, rather than using `private`.

Comment: Note that `#pragma omp critical` protects the next line only (without braces), you still have data race on the next 2 lines. It is much better to use reduction (if possible) or use atomic operations. How big is `ParticleN`?

Comment: @ Laci Thanks for pointing out the braces problem. I tried to use #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:f_kewald[:ParticleN][:3]) but didn't work saying that "the array section is not contiguous".

Comment: @ Victor Thanks for mentioning the proper way of declaring the variables, I have now modified the code.

Comment: if `f_kewald` is allocated by `alloc_2d_double`, then it is indeed continuous in memory, but you have to access it as a 1D array. Note that your stack has to be big enough to store a local copy for all the threads. From performance point of view it would be much better to use one dimensional arrays.

Comment: So, my suggestion is to allocate a `ParticleNx3`-sized 1D array for `f_kewald`. In this case, reduction can be used, and, more importantly, the compiler can properly vectorize your code. Another suggestion is to use `const` variables wherever possible. It may help the compiler to better optimize your code, especially in the case of parallel code using shared variables.

Comment: @ Laci Now, I have used three 1D arrays and reduction over those, which gives me a better speed up than using the omp critical section. I have modified the code accordingly. Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Comment: After the edits, the question contains an answer to itself. Probably not useful to anyone reading it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified view of your code:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for ...
    for(k=0; k<kcount; k++){
            ...
            f_kewald[i][0] += ...
            ...
    }
```

It's clear that different threads will update `f_kewald[i][0]` simultaneously, leading to errors. This happens for all `i`.

When you stuff all your code updating `f_kewald` into a critical section, this helps — now threads wait for each other. But still the updates are in arbitrary order, and the critical section doesn't discriminate between different values of `i`.

I suggest you parallelize your calculations only at one level - decide whether you want to do it at the outer loop, or at the inner loops, not both. Assuming your `ParticleN` is big enough, you don't need to parallelize your outer loop. This is the easy case.

---

If your `ParticleN` can be small, better parallelize your outer loop, but then you have to fix the synchronization problem of `f_kewald` somehow. Some ideas:

- Switch your loops inside-out
- Break your outer loop into several pieces, each of which contains only one inner loop

This is a bad situation — you have to tweak your code, and it may be hard or impossible. If you can avoid it at all (see above), please do!

---

Regardless of anything, multiple people advised not using `private` to control allocation of variables to threads. This is good advice! You should declare your variables in the proper C scope instead of using `private`. This will make it easier to transform your code (if you ever need to), and will prevent unpleasant surprises (when you forget just one variable in your giant `private` list).

Comment: In my case ParticleN ~ 5000 and kcount ~2000, in which case I assume the inner loop parallelization will work fine. I have now removed the variables from private and declared them inside. However, is there a way to not use the omp critical and use reduction in f_kewald[i][0]?